# Is a book recommendation site recommendation question valid?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Are there good services for similar series recommendations?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234850/are-there-good-services-for-similar-series-recommendations)

I'm on the fence. Since it's not restricted to fantasy and sci-fi, it's arguably off-topic anyhow, but is asking for a site that offers a particular sort of recommendation on topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say these types of questions are off topic. It's a borderline recommendation question but it also falls somewhat into the following [off topic categories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

- > every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

  Whilst it's not really asking for your favourite recommendation site, it is in a way, again borderline here though. But of course every answer here will be equally valid.
- > your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

  It is this type of question with the caveat of the ones the OP is using aren't quite fulfilling their needs.

The close reason itself is:

> Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they do not fit our questions and answers format. Feel free to ask about people's favorites in chat.

This is a recommendation question just not for lists of works but for a site that recommends books; still asking for recommendations though. The reason for *why* these questions are off topic is the same.

Note that for the reasons above even if we didn't have a specific close reason here I would say it is likely to be closed under "Opinion based" or "Needs more focus" anyway.

Comment: It's off-topic for about five different overlapping reasons. Take your pick, really.